# Is there any Fastest method to convert Datetime to string with Format?

Tags: datetime, datetimepicker, tostring, datetime-format

Following convertion with date format, taking much time to execute while it comes inside a loop.

*date.ToString("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm");*

is there any fastest method to do the same process?

Answer (score 1):

You can you use SimpleDateFormatter to format your date, and then print the output.
Below is the sample code snippet to get the desired output:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this may be faster `String.Format("{0:g}", date);`